# How can i export a class to module and import the same in another module in typescript with angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-forms, ng-modules

I have a class(`IGeneric`) which is exported to the module A and I imported that Module(A) in  module B, but I could not use that exported class(`IGeneric`) in the module B.

Note : that exported class is not a component,directive and service.it is a plain typescript class

Any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance. The class which I am trying to export

```
export class IGeneric{
header : any[];
content : [{
   lable :any,
   value :any
}]
}
```

Comment: how are you trying to use/consume the `IGeneric` class?

Answer (score 2):

There is a trick to **hide** the details within a module by [`barrel files`](https://medium.com/@adrianfaciu/barrel-files-to-use-or-not-to-use-75521cd18e65), via which you can

- just introduce the barrel file (normally named as `index.ts`) to that module, and
- export everything you intend to export in that barrel file, and then
- import the *module path* whenever you try to use the exported class/interface or components;

As a follow-up, there is an another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49060157/how-to-properly-import-export-classes-across-angular-modules) to elaborate what you can achieve by using barrel files.

Answer (score 1):

`index` file will be helpful to you if you don't want to show the entire path of your class

Assume that you have a module `MyModule` within which you have `IGeneric` class

igeneric.model.ts

```
export class IGeneric{
header : any[];
content : [{
   lable :any,
   value :any
}]
```

Index file should be inside your Module `MyModule` directory

index.ts

```
export * from 'app/MyModule/igeneric.model';
```

Then in your component you can import

```
import {IGeneric} from 'app/MyModule'
```

Comment: a regular typescript class does not need to referenced in angular's providers array

Comment: @danimal Agreed, but if it has to be injected within the component, then it is required.

Comment: OP doesn't mention injection and says it's NOT a service (hence not a provider in need of injection)

Comment: Hi Amit see i have two modules A and B.now i have exported the IGeneric class in module A, now in Module B i am imported the Module A. but still i could not able to find that IGeneric in the component which is in Module B

Comment: @praveen How are you trying to access your class in component?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like an ES6/Typescript module import/export issue rather than an issue for (the completely different and separate) NgModule system. 
If this is the case, then you simply need to `import` the class you want from the file you want at the top of the .ts file, e.g.:

```
import { IGeneric } from './relative/path/to/definition';
```

and then use the class as you would normally in a component/service etc

```
public generic: IGeneric;
```

Comment: That i can do but i don't want to expose the path. i need it from module where as i already had it in my module so i am trying to get it from that

Comment: so you want to be able to use an /instance/ of the class somewhere else?

Comment: yes i will just import that module and i want to use all the classes inside that module